# How to get GeoCoordinates from LocationName

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i want to know, if there is any possibility to find out the geoCoordinate from a specific location. I have the following code:

```
        delMap.Heading = 0;
        delMap.CartographicMode = MapCartographicMode.Road;
        delMap.LandmarksEnabled = true;
        delMap.ZoomLevel = 8;
        delMap.Center = new GeoCoordinate(47.6097, -122.3331);

        MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay
        {
            GeoCoordinate = delMap.Center,
            Content = new Ellipse
            {
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
                Width = 10,
                Height = 10
            }
        };
        MapLayer layer = new MapLayer();
        layer.Add(overlay);

        delMap.Layers.Add(layer);
```

it displays a point at the delmap.Center location, just as expectet. But now, i need to find out how to center the map, if i only know the name of the geographic location. For instance "New York".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map has no concept of "New York", you can only center it at geographic coordinates. You need to *get* the coordinates for a given location.

To do that, either build a list of coordinates for locations (if you have a limited and known number of location) using Google or Bing maps or find a web service that will give you a coordinate for a given name.

---

EDIT: What you need is [geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding). Here is the Google API reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/.

Comment: Do You know a Tutorial, how i can achieve this in google or bing maps?